# Does AWS Api GateWay supports OData?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, odata, graphql

I want to use Odata as a query builder in my api's hosted on aws lamda and exposed using AWS api gateway. On reading several aws documentation, I found that people have faced several issues with this earlier. Can someone please tell me about whether it's supported and if not what can be an alternative for the same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**OData** at its core is just **REST** relying on web standards and as such will be supported by web-standard compliant tech stack, so will work with **AWS API Gateway** and **Lambdas**.

However you have to ensure that you can **pass custom headers** and **query parameters** to your function, which used to be a bit tricky.

It used to be the case that you had to pass headers inside a request body as lambdas had only visibility to the request body: [see this AWS technical documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda/).

However since **Sept 2017** you can setup [lambda with proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-set-up-lambda-proxy-integration-on-proxy-resource) which will proxy request and response headers to and from your lambda verbatim.

HTH.

Comment: Here is a AWS forum link regarding discussion on Odata support, people have mentioned that they are facing issues while passing query parameter as a part of request URL. And these are some basic functionalities which are required to be supported as part of API's.  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228788

Comment: That discussion around the issues is dated to 2016... here are current up to date limitations and known issues: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html